# Advanced search in Django using python

Tags: django, python-3.x, search, django-models, django-queryset

I am currently working on django. Now, I want achieve the advanced search, to be more specifically, achieve precise searching using imprecise key words.

For example, when I type `'a$c'`, all the matching results will be `'ac'`, `'abc'`, `'a!c'`, `'Ac'`, `'AC'` and so on. Basically, '$(or maybe other characters)' could be numbers, could be letters or nothing. Is there any method to do this?
BTW, my code for achieving the basic search function is written as below:

```
class MetaboliteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['id', 'name', 'compartment', 'charge', 'formula']

class ReactionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['id', 'name','metabolites', 'gene_reaction_rule', 'subsystem']

class GeneAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['id', 'name', '']
```

Comment: What about [django's contains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#icontains) query method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override [`get_search_results()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L934) in a `ModelAdmin` class to give you more control over object search functionality.

The example below uses Django's `iregex` lookup to do a case-insensitive search across all search_fields when the `$` character is specified. It basically replaces the `$` with a `.*` which is regex for "any character, zero or more times".

```
from functools import reduce
from django.db.models import Q

class MetaboliteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['id', 'name', 'compartment', 'charge', 'formula']

    def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        if '$' in search_term:
            search_term = search_term.replace('$', '.*')
            return queryset.filter(reduce(lambda x, y: x | y,
                                          [Q(**{'{}__iregex'.format(field): search_term})
                                           for field in self.search_fields])), True
        return super().get_search_results(request, queryset, search_term)
```

When the `$` character is not specified, the search functionality behaves as normal.

Comment: So appreciate for your help! But when I copied this code to my project, it turned out that 'reduce' is not defined. What else should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: What version of Python are you using? If you are using Python 3.5 or above, you should use `from functools import reduce` like in the above example. Otherwise you can omit the import, and Python will use the builtin `reduce` function.

Comment: problem solved and worked functionally! Thanks a lot!